# Storing integer solutions to equation as a list

Tags: list-manipulation

Let $z$ be a complex number and define
$$Q_z(c,d) = c^2\vert z \vert^2 + 2cd\textrm{Re}(z) + d^2.$$
Define for $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$
$$S_{\lambda} = \{(c,d) \in \mathbb{N}_0 \times \mathbb{Z} : \gcd(c,d) = 1, Q_z(c,d) = \lambda\}.$$

Can I store the elements of $S_{\lambda}$ as a list in Mathematica? I tried

```
S[l_]:=Table[c, d, Assumptions -> GCD[c,d] = 1, Q[c, d] = l]
```

but it complained that "Iterator {d} does not have appropriate bounds".

Comment: Those are not assumptions. You are actually trying to solve some equation. I don't know how to solve the actual task, but a table could only be used to try all combinations, so not suitable for what you want to achieve.

Comment: This is a math question, not really a question about Mathematica. To the extent that it might be about Mathematica's `Table`, the ref guide page should be consulted in regard to appropriate syntax.

Comment: If `lambda` is an integer and `z` a Gaussian integer, then there is probbly a good way to find all `(c,d)` pairs by putting together factorizations of `lambda` with `GaussianIntegers->True` option. (Use `(c*z+d)*(c*zbar+d)=lambda` as a rewrite of the `Q` equation.)

Answer (score 2):

So i don't get this thing solved analyticly but one can simply test numerical in intervals.

First: define the Q-Function:

```
Q[z_, c_, d_] := c^2*Abs[z]^2 + 2*c*d*Re[z] + d^2
```

Now, if we define $\lambda$ and $z$ (at example: $\lambda=5,z=1+i$) and the range to $c\times d=[-50,50]\times[-50,50]$ :

```
DeleteCases[
 Flatten[
  Table[If[GCD[c, d] == 1, If[Q[z, c, d] == L, {c, d}]], {c, -50, 50}, {d, -50, 50}]
  , 1]
 , Null]
```

> {{-2, 1}, {-2, 3}, {-1, -1}, {-1, 3}, {1, -3}, {1, 
>     1}, {2, -3}, {2, -1}}

For performance reasons i would use [`Do`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Do.html) instead of [`Table`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Table.html):

```
Flatten[Reap[
   Do[If[GCD[c, d] == 1, If[Q[z, c, d] == L, Sow[{c, d}]]], {c, -50, 50}, {d, -50, 50}]]
   [[2]], 1]
```

We can even nicely visualize this:

```
cdPair[\[Lambda]_, Z_] := Flatten[Reap[Do[If[GCD[c, d] == 1, 
      If[c^2*Abs[Z]^2 + 2*c*d*Re[z] + d^2 == \[Lambda], Sow[{c, d}]]], {c, -20, 20}, {d, -20, 20}]][[2]], 1]
ListPlot[DeleteCases[Table[cdPair[l, 1 + I], {l, -200, 200}], {}]]
ListPlot[DeleteCases[Table[cdPair[l, 1 + I], {l, -500, 500}], {}], 
 Joined -> True]
```

> [image: Blockquote]
>
> [image: Blockquote]